# How can i add diff variables in the weather command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is a weather command and in this i wanna add some more variables like `visibility`, `wind speed`, `feels like`.just like the variable `current_temparature`. So, i was looking for some help in how to make make those variables

```
api_key = "apikey"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
@client.command(aliases = ["temprature","temp"])
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with channel.typing():
            y = x["main"]
            current_temperature = y["temp"]
            current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
            current_pressure = y["pressure"]
            current_humidity = y["humidity"]
          
            
            
            
            z = x["weather"]
            weather_description = z[0]["description"]

            weather_description = z[0]["description"]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Weather in {city_name}",
                              color=ctx.author.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
            embed.add_field(name="Descripition", value=f"**{weather_description}**")
            embed.add_field(name="Temperature(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**")
            embed.add_field(name="Humidity(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Atmospheric Pressure(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**")
            
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send("City not found.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first have to check if that data is supplied by the weather API you're using. If it is, locate where that data is in your response `y`, and add it to the message in a similair manner to the other variables.

I would take a look at the documentation of the API youre using to see if those statistics are available.

Edit: The data you wish to add can be found in the response as follows:

```
x["visibility"]
x["wind"]["speed"]
x["main"]["feels_like"]
```

You can add them to your message with for example:

```
embed.add_field(name="Wind speed", value=f"**{x["wind"]["speed"]}**")
```

The response object is documented here:
https://openweathermap.org/current#parameter

Comment: thank you so much it do work and for explaining how it works as well